# Tasks/Queues mangament in amazon aws

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I'm looking for a solution to add items into a queue and execute them one-by-one in a similar method to google appengine's tasks manager. Each task will be executed using a http request to a php script.

As i'm using amazon, i understood that the best practice is using the SNS service that will be responsible for receiving new tasks, adding them to a queue (Amazon's SQS service) and also inform my php worker that a new task has been pushed into the queue so he can look for it and execute it.
There are several issues with that method (like the need to limit the number of workers instances via the worker itself or just the possibility that the task won't be in the queue when we call the worker because we add the task to the queue in the same time).

I would like to hear if there are any better options or a nicer way of implementing a tasks manager. I preffer using the amazon's services but i'm open to any new suggestion, looking for the best method. Features that are missing in amazon like FIFO and priorities support would also be a nice addition.

Thanks!
Ben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a good solution.
AWS Beanstalk service is apparently offering an option to define a new elastic-beanstalk instance as a "worker" or a "web server". in case you define it as a "Worker", you'll be able to attach it to a sqs queue and it will be responsible for polling the queue and performing the task (with the code you deploy to the instance).